# Toggles a class on an element when another element is clicked React

Tags: reactjs

I have this component in react. I would like whenever I click an a tag with class 'btn' to add/toggle a class 'open' to div with class 'smenu' within the same li element. I implemented it naively like the following, but I am sure there should be another more efficient way. Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const AccordioMenu = () => {
  const [activeP, setActiveP] = useState(false);
  const [activeM, setActiveM] = useState(false);

  const toggleActiveP = () => {
    setActiveP(!activeP);
  };
  const toggleActiveM = () => {
    setActiveM(!activeM);
  };

  let btnclassesP = ['smenu']
  if(activeP){
    btnclassesP.push('open')
  }
  let btnclassesM = ['smenu']
  if(activeM){
    btnclassesM.push('open')
  }
  return (
    <div className="middle">
      <div className="menu">
        <li className="item" id="profile">
          <a className='btn' href="#" onClick={toggleActiveP}>
            Profile
          </a>
          <div className={btnclassesP.join(' ')}>
            <a href="">Posts</a>
            <a href="">Pictures</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li className="item" id="messages">
          <a className="btn" href="#" onClick={toggleActiveM}>
            Messages
          </a>
          <div className={btnclassesM.join(' ')}>
            <a href="">New</a>
            <a href="">Sent</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li className="item" id="logout">
          <a className="btn" href="#">
            Logout
          </a>
        </li>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AccordioMenu;
```

Comment: That's pretty good, I suppose you can simplify it even further by using a single state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to simplify this even further you could just use one-state value, that way the component has a single source of truth to share.

Let's have a state that stores an array of identifiers. Each identifier is associated with a different set of links. We'll use "message" and "profile" as the identifiers. Naturally, if there is nothing in the array, then all sub-links should be collapsed.

Then we can use just an event-handler to add/remove the identifier into the `state` array. Lastly, we can use an inline-style to determine whether that set of links corresponding to the identifier should include the `open` class.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const AccordioMenu = () => {
  const [ selectedItems, setSelectedItems ] = useState([])

  //event-handler accepts an identifer-string as an argument
  const handleSelect = (identifier) => {
     //creates a copy of the original state to avoid state-mutation
     const selectedItemsCopy = [...selectedItems]

     //check if the idenifier that was passed already exists in the state
     if(selectedItemsCopy.includes(identifier)){
         //it already exists, which means the menu-links are expanded
         const foundIndex = selectedItemsCopy.indexOf(identifier)
         //you've clicked it to hide it. so remove the identifier from the state
         selectedItemsCopy.splice(foundIndex, 1)
         setSelectedItems(selectedItemsCopy)
     } else {
        //if identifier was not found in state. then add it.
        setSelectedItems([...selectedItems, identifier])
     }
  }

  return (
    <div className="middle">
      <div className="menu">
        <li className="item" id="profile">
          //set up handler to pass identifier
          <a className='btn' href="#" onClick={() => handleSelect("profile")}>
            Profile
          </a>
          <div className={selectedItems.includes("profile") ? "smenu open" : "smenu"}>
            <a href="">Posts</a>
            <a href="">Pictures</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li className="item" id="messages">
          //set up handler to pass identifier
          <a className="btn" href="#" onClick={() => handleSelect("message")}>
            Messages
          </a>
          <div className={selectedItems.includes("messages") ? "smenu open" : "smenu"}>
            <a href="">New</a>
            <a href="">Sent</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li className="item" id="logout">
          <a className="btn" href="#">
            Logout
          </a>
        </li>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AccordioMenu;
```

Comment: This works. Please mark this one as answer if this has solved your issue @BlackMath

Comment: It works but it doesn't toggle the class. I want to toggle the class on each click. This is how my original code works.

Comment: @BlackMath hmmm I'm not sure what you mean by toggle the class. Visually does it accomplish what you're trying to do?

Comment: Let me explain in terms of functionality. The above component is basically a menu with three main links: Profile, Messages, and Logout. The first two links have sub-menus that are hidden at first. I want when I click Profile, for example, the first time, for its sub-menu to appear, but to disappear only when I click Profile again. Your method toggle the class only once, which means if you click Profile twice the sub-menu will remain. Also, your method doesn't allow both sub-menus to be displayed simultaneously, which not what I want exactly.

Comment: @BlackMath I see! Now that makes more sense to me :)

Comment: @BlackMath can you try my updated solution and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Can you please add some comments to explain how this logic works. I didn't understand it.

Comment: @BlackMath sure! Did you try it out, does it work :) ?

Comment: @BlackMath just wrote some comments for you

Comment: OK. I got it now. It works perfectly now without going into state management.

Answer (score 2):

[Christopher Ngo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10030970/christopher-ngo)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57894672/4035) is a good answer that can work.

I just want to provide a different way to handle the same scenario using `useReducer`.

If you have multiple states that works in conjunction with each other, it sometimes makes it easy to use a reducer, to "co-locate" the related state changes.

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";

const initialState = {
  profileClass: 'smenu',
  menuClass: 'smenu',
};

//  You can see which state are related and how they should change together.
// And you can also see from the action type what each state is doing.
const menuClassReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "mark profile as selected":
      return { profileClass: 'smenu open', menuClass: 'smenu' };
    case "mark menu as selected":
      return { profileClass: 'smenu', menuClass: 'smenu open' };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const AccordioMenu = () => {
  const [{profileClass, menuClass}, dispatch] = useReducer(menuClassReducer, initialState);

  const toggleActiveP = () => {
    dispatch({type: 'mark profile as selected'})
  };
  const toggleActiveM = () => {
    dispatch({type: 'mark menu as selected'})
  };

  return (
    <div className="middle">
      <div className="menu">
        <li className="item" id="profile">
          <a className="btn" href="#" onClick={toggleActiveP}>
            Profile
          </a>
                              1️⃣ 
          <div className={profileClass}>
            <a href="">Posts</a>
            <a href="">Pictures</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li className="item" id="messages">
          <a className="btn" href="#" onClick={toggleActiveM}>
            Messages
          </a>
                           2️⃣ 
          <div className={menuClass}>
            <a href="">New</a>
            <a href="">Sent</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li className="item" id="logout">
          <a className="btn" href="#">
            Logout
          </a>
        </li>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can see 1️⃣ & 2️⃣ above that you can simply set the state classes that are returned from the reducer.

Those two classes (`menuClass` & `profileClass`) are updated automatically on click as events are dispatched from `toggleActiveM` & `toggleActiveP` respectively.

If you plan to do something with the "selected" state, you can simply update the reducer by handling new states and you'd still know how each state are updated together in one place.

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";

const initialState = {
  isProfileSelected: false,
  isMenuSelected: false,
  profileClass: "smenu",
  menuClass: "smenu"
};
const menuClassReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "mark profile as selected":
      return {
        isProfileSelected: true,
        isMenuSelected: false,
        profileClass: "smenu open",
        menuClass: "smenu"
      };
    case "mark menu as selected":
      return {
        isProfileSelected: false,
        isMenuSelected: true,
        profileClass: "smenu",
        menuClass: "smenu open"
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const AccordioMenu = () => {
  const [
    { profileClass, menuClass, isProfileSelected, isMenuSelected },
    dispatch
  ] = useReducer(menuClassReducer, initialState);

  const toggleActiveP = () => {
    dispatch({ type: "mark profile as selected" });
  };
  const toggleActiveM = () => {
    dispatch({ type: "mark menu as selected" });
  };
  return // do something with newly added states;
};
```

Comment: I was aware of using Context and Reducer, but I thought there might have been a simpler way. In Vanilla JS it's much simpler in my opinion.

Comment: @BlackMath Yeah. React is state driven, so unobstrusive JavaScript way could be easier for some cases.